# How to move a holonomic robot/object in Gazebo from one position to another?

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a cylinder model which uses the Gazebo_ROS_planar_move plugin (libgazebo_ros_planar_move.so).
It uses the Carrot planner for the global path.

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"/>
```

When I command it to move from one position to another, it uses the TrajectoryPlannerROS local planner to define local paths for a non-holonomic robot. I tried setting it to SimpleTrajectoryGenerator in the base_local_planner_params.yaml, but it still still works like a non-holonomic robot.

```
SimpleTrajectoryGenerator:
  max_vel_x: 0.5
  min_vel_x: 0.1
  max_vel_y: 0.5
  min_vel_y: 0.1
  max_rotational_vel: 2.0
  min_in_place_rotational_vel: 0.1

  acc_lim_th: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: true
  y_vels:  [-0.3, -0.1, 0.1, 0.3]

  occdist_scale: 0.1
```

I just want the object to move in a straight path from one position to another (rotation does not matter at all, as it as a vertical cylinder).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235747/how-to-move-a-holonomic-robot/object-in-gazebo-from-one-position-to-another?/) by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2016-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Write a simple proportional controller like the one below:

```
using namespace std;

double curr_pos_x, curr_pos_y, curr_orientation_angle_x,quat_z,quat_w;
double new_pos_x, new_pos_y, new_orientation_angle_x;

ros::Publisher *vel_pub;

std::vector<std::array<double,2>> waypoints;

void poseCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry& msgIn)
{
  curr_pos_x = msgIn.pose.pose.position.x;
  curr_pos_y = msgIn.pose.pose.position.y;
  quat_z = msgIn.pose.pose.orientation.z;
  quat_w = msgIn.pose.pose.orientation.w;
  curr_orientation_angle_x = 2*atan2(quat_z,quat_w);
  // cout<<"Angle ====>>"<<(float)(orientation_angle_x*(180.0/3.1415))<<endl;
}

void updatePosition(ros::NodeHandle nh, string pose_str, double& temp_pos_x, double& temp_pos_y, double& temp_orientation_angle_x)
{
    ros::Rate rate(5);
    ros::Subscriber sub2 = nh.subscribe(pose_str, 1, &poseCallback);

    curr_pos_x = 0;
    while(ros::ok()) {
        
        ros::spinOnce();

        if(curr_pos_x!=0)
        {
            temp_pos_x = curr_pos_x; temp_pos_y = curr_pos_y;
            temp_orientation_angle_x = curr_orientation_angle_x;

            break;
        }
        else
            // cout<<"\t Updating Position: Waiting for information..."<<endl;

        // Wait until it's time for another iteration.
        rate.sleep();       
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv){


    if(argc!=2)
    {
      std::cout<<"Not enough arguments!! (" << argc << "). Exiting!!"<<std::endl;
      return 0;
    }

  std::array<int,2> pos = {1,1};
  std::array<int,2> next_pos;

  char *robot_name = argv[1];

  string pose_str =  "/" ;
  pose_str += robot_name;
  pose_str += "/odom";

  string vel_str = "/";
  vel_str += robot_name;
  vel_str += "/cmd_vel";

  string node_name = "square_goals_";
  node_name += robot_name;

  ros::init(argc, (char **)argv, node_name );
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  waypoints.push_back({4,4});
  waypoints.push_back({4,2});
  waypoints.push_back({2,2});
  waypoints.push_back({2,4});


  vel_pub = new ros::Publisher(nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>(vel_str, 1000));

  bool set_new_goal = true;

  cout<<"Updating Position... \n";
  updatePosition(nh, pose_str, curr_pos_x, curr_pos_y, curr_orientation_angle_x);
  cout<<" Position Updated. \n";

  int i = 0;
  int curr_goal_idx = 0;
  // for(int i=0;i>=0;) // Change this for the number of waypoints
  while(ros::ok())
  {

    // cout<<"Going to waypoint # = "<<i<<endl;

  if(set_new_goal == true)
  {

    cout<<"Curr Goal IDX: = "<<curr_goal_idx<<endl;
    cout<<"Prev Goal Pos: X = "<<new_pos_x<<", Y = "<<new_pos_y<<";"<<endl;

    curr_goal_idx += 1;
    curr_goal_idx = curr_goal_idx % 4;
    next_pos = {waypoints[curr_goal_idx][0], waypoints[curr_goal_idx][1]};

    new_pos_x = next_pos[0];
    new_pos_y = next_pos[1];

    cout<<"New Goal IDX: = "<<curr_goal_idx<<endl;
    cout<<"New Goal Pos: X = "<<new_pos_x<<", Y = "<<new_pos_y<<";"<<endl;

    set_new_goal = false;
    i++;
    cout<<"===================================="<<endl;
  }

  // cout<<"Updating Position... \n";
  updatePosition(nh, pose_str, curr_pos_x, curr_pos_y, curr_orientation_angle_x);
  // cout<<"Robot Position Updated. \n";

  double dist_to_waypoint = sqrt(pow(curr_pos_x-new_pos_x,2)+pow(curr_pos_y-new_pos_y,2));
  double vel_x = min(2.5,2*dist_to_waypoint)*(-(curr_pos_x-new_pos_x)/dist_to_waypoint);
  double vel_y = min(2.5,2*dist_to_waypoint)*(-(curr_pos_y-new_pos_y)/dist_to_waypoint);

  geometry_msgs::Twist msgOut;
  msgOut.linear.x = vel_x;
  msgOut.linear.y = vel_y;
  msgOut.angular.z = 0;

  // cout<<"Sending angular velocity => vel_x = "<<msgOut.linear.x<<"; vel_y = "<<msgOut.linear.y<<endl;
  vel_pub->publish(msgOut);

  // cout<<"Distance to waypoint = "<<dist_to_waypoint<<endl;
  if(dist_to_waypoint < 0.2)
  {
     set_new_goal = true;
  }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) with karma: 117 on 2016-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0